# How to get objects linked to objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model, foreign-keys, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm confused about something in Rails (using Rails 5).  I have this model

```
class MyEventActivity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event_activity
end
```

and what I want to do is get a list of all the objects linked to it, in other words, all the "event_activity" objects.  I thought this would do the trick

```
my_event_activities = MyEventActivity.all.pluck(:event_activity)
```

but its giving me this SQL error

```
   (2.3ms)  SELECT "event_activity" FROM "my_event_activities"
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "event_activity" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "event_activity" FROM "my_event_activities"
```

How do I get the objects linked to the MyEventActivity objects?  Note that I don't want just the IDs, I want the whole object.

**Edit:** This is the PostGres table as requested

```
eactivit=# \d event_activities;
                                            Table "public.event_activities"
          Column          |            Type             |                           Modifiers
--------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 id                       | integer                     | not null default nextval('event_activities_id_seq'::regclass)
 name                     | character varying           |
 abbrev                   | character varying           |
 attendance             | bigint                      |
 created_at               | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at               | timestamp without time zone | not null
```

Comment: did you put set has_many property in your event_activity model ? And it's look like your column isn't present in the model. Can you add the database migration you did also please

Comment: Could you show the event_activity model?

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
EventActivity.joins(:my_event_activities).distinct
```

Returns all `EventActivity` objects that have associated `MyEventActivity` records

Or more along the lines of what you've already tried:

```
EventActivity.where(id: MyEventActivity.all.pluck(:event_activity_id).uniq)
```

But the first one is preferable for its brevity and performance.

#### Update to explain why the first option should be preferred

#### TL;DR much faster and more readable

Assume we have 100 `event_activities`, and all but the last (`id: 100`) have 100 `my_event_activities` for a total of 9900 `my_event_activities`.

`EventActivity.where(id: MyEventActivity.all.pluck(:event_activity_id).uniq)` performs two SQL queries:

`SELECT "my_event_activities"."event_activity_id" FROM "my_event_activities"` which will return an Array of 9900 non-unique `event_activity_id`s. We want to reduce this to unique ids to optimize the second query, so we call `Array#uniq` which has its own performance cost on large arrays, reducing 9900 down to 99. Then we can call the second query: `SELECT  "event_activities".* FROM "event_activities" WHERE "event_activities"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, ... 97, 98, 99)`

`EventActivity.joins(:my_event_activities).distinct` performs only one SQL query: `SELECT  DISTINCT "event_activities".* FROM "event_activities" INNER JOIN "my_event_activities" ON "my_event_activities"."event_activity_id" = "event_activities"."id"`. Once we drop into the database we never have to switch back to Ruby to perform some expensive process and then make a second trip back to the database. `joins` is designed for performing these types of chainable and composable queries in situations like this.

The performance difference can be checked with a simple benchmark. With an actual Postgres database loaded with 100 `event_activities`, 99 of which have 100 `my_event_activities`:

```
require 'benchmark/ips'
require_relative 'config/environment'

Benchmark.ips do |bm|
  bm.report('joins.distinct') do
    EventActivity.joins(:my_event_activities).distinct
  end

  bm.report('pluck.uniq') do
    EventActivity.where(id: MyEventActivity.all.pluck(:event_activity_id).uniq)
  end

  bm.compare!
end
```

And the results:

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
      joins.distinct     5.922k i/100ms
          pluck.uniq     7.000  i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
      joins.distinct     71.504k (± 3.5%) i/s -    361.242k in   5.058311s
          pluck.uniq     73.459  (±13.6%) i/s -    364.000  in   5.061892s

Comparison:
      joins.distinct:    71503.9 i/s
          pluck.uniq:       73.5 i/s - 973.38x  slower
```

973x slower :-O ! The `joins` method is meant to be used for things just like this, and this is one of the happy cases in Ruby where more readable is also more performant.

Comment: Why is the first one preferable?

Comment: @Natalia please see the updated answer explaining why it should be preferred. hope this helps

Comment: Because of the performance difference I want to get your first answer to work, but I get the error, "ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'EventActivity' to association named 'my_event_activities'; perhaps you misspelled it?".  The second solution works, though, performance inefficiencies and all.

Comment: @Natalia what does your `MyEventActivity` class look like?

Comment: @Natalia sorry, i meant EventActivity. what kind of association does it have to my_event_activities?

Comment: @Natalia this error will be raised if `EventActivity` does not `has_many :event_activities`. Does it `has_one :event_activity`? If so change the query to `EventActivity.joins(:my_event_activity).distinct.count`. If not, it should have one of these associations so you can run queries like this.

Comment: @Natalia Is this solution working for you now then? If so could you upvote and accept it?